# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cassandra.core.Cancellable with spring-data-cassandra version 1.2.1

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I'm getting the following exception when using current GA version 1.2.1. The repository object is autowired in my sample code.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/vmware/vrack/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration.cassandraTemplate(AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java:85)
    at mine.samples.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$831105a6.CGLIB$cassandraTemplate$5(<generated>)
    at mine.samples.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$831105a6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2a9e6652.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at mine.samples.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$831105a6.cassandraTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cassandra.core.Cancellable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:136)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 58 more
```

Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much snooping around I found out that the issue was due to an older version of spring-cql being used.

I fixed it by using dependency management to explicitly use the latest spring-cql version. Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cql</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

The spring-data-cassandra 1.1.3 release does not have this problem. You can switch back to that if you just need to get things running.

(I am also watching this issue to see if it gets fixed.)

Comment: Thanks. But 1.1.3 doesn't seem to support a lot of features that I require like declarative query methods, for example.